# Отправка пакетов через прокси сервер SOCKS5 используя только стандартную библиотеку в Питоне

Tags: python, socks5

Как в Python3 **стандартными средствами** отправлять пакеты на сервер через прокси сервер SOCKS5?

Например, через:  `urllib.request`, `http.client` и т.д.?

Comment: Чем не устравиает PySocks https://github.com/Anorov/PySocks ?

Comment: нужно именно стандартными средствами)

Comment: что Вы понимаете под "стандартными" средствами?

Comment: через стандартные библиотеки, которые изначально встроенные в python, а не сторонние..

они же: socket, urllib.request, http.client и тд..

Comment: IMHO никак, я не нашел в свое время поддержки SOCKS в Питоне "из коробки"

Comment: Стандартные библиотеки используют настройки системы как бы, если я не ошибаюсь. Можно попытаться менять системные настройки, но оно Вам точно надо?

Comment: нет, оно мне точно не нужно)

Comment: Вот тут что то интересное по теме: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html

Comment: А вообще такие библиотеки как requests например поддерживают разного уровня прокси на уровне самих библиотек. Зачем изобретать велосипед?

Comment: Я знаю, я работал с этими библиотеками, но мне нужно через стандартные.. не спрашивайте зачем, просто очень нужно.

Comment: Отказ обосновать извращения сильно снижает шансы получить ответ :) В самых крайних случаях всегда можно выкачать PySocks и сделать его частью своего скрипта

Comment: pysocks это чистый питон, если нельзя ничего устанавливать, то просто рядом со своим кодом положите (к примеру, в папочку `your_package/_vendor` и импортируйте: `from your_package._vendor import socks`)

Comment: @ast см. первый комментарий...